# Workflow lifecycle?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am looking for a document/diagram that shows states a workflow goes through (Idle, Complete, Aborted, Deleted, Unloaded, Unhandled Exception)

Yes, I lmgtfy'd it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow goes through various states depending on whether you're using persistence service or not. For a diagram you can have a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/moustafa/archive/2006/03/02/542459.aspx The only thing that has been missed in the article is when a workflow is cancelled. The only difference between Cancel and Terminate is that terminating workflow requires a reason whereas canceling it does not require one.

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Is that link valid for WF4? (the post is dated 2006, so it was done for WF3)

Comment: The diagram is also valid for WF4.

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't any diagrams out there believe it or not. However, here is an article that explains it textually -- http://dotnetrobert.com/?q=node/100 -- quite well.